# java Tokenizer slip

Tags: java, split

I'd like to tokenizer a String line into tokens (stock in to a table of String )and I can only use java.io.*
It's to implement a calculator.

For example:
First line: 1+2+3
Second line: 1+ 2*3 (this one with space between tokens)

into table{"1","+","2","+","3"}

I thought about split any Idea?

Comment: You can't use `java.util.StringTokenizer`?

Comment: @Jim `StringTokenizer` has been replaced because it's bulky.

Comment: No, I can't I knew this class but only io. It's tricky

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use [`java.io.StreamTokenizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what manji said, if you really want to do implement a calculator you will need to *parse* your tokens after they have been tokenized.

For instance, if you have the expression:

> 1+2+3*(4+5)

you'll need to create an *Abstract Syntax Tree* so that the expression will be evaluated correctly.

Regexes alone are not enough to solve this problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished pretty easily.

```
 String text  = "1+2+3";

        StringBuilder seperatedString = new StringBuilder();

        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char aChar = chars[i];
            if(!Character.isSpaceChar(aChar)) {
              seperatedString.append(aChar).append(",");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The tokenized string"+ seperatedString);
```

Or you can use Regex like @glowcoder has mentioned. When questioned on how you know regex, you could say you used RegexBuddy.

Answer (score 0):

To scan the input, I recommend java.util.Scanner.